# Array of Comparables in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, comparable

I get the following error in my code. I'm very rusty of C++, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Error Message:

```
Error: Field has incompatible type 'int []'
```

Code:

```
template<typename Comparable> class OrderedCollection
{         
private:
    Comparable data[];  //ERROR CAUSED BY THIS LINE
    int _size;
    int _current;
    const int MAX_SIZE = 100;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A probable fix for this is to use a second template parameter that accepts a size_t.

```
template<typename Comparable, size_t MAX_SIZE = 100> class OrderedCollection
    {

    private:
        Comparable data[MAX_SIZE];  //Error should be gone
        int _size;
        int _current;
```

Comment: Magic numbers are bad. Use `std::vector<Comparable>` instead.

Comment: @bames53: You're misusing the term "magic numbers", but you're right that a `vector` is usually preferred to a fixed size container like that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `const` array size, array size must be known at compile time.

Something like this should fix:

```
  Comparable data[MAX_SIZE];
```

Comment: While this is true since C++ does not support Variable length array's(VLA) the code in Q will usually compile using a compiler extension for VLA(*unless OP is using `-pedantic`*). The error does not say *Incomplete type* the error says *incompatible type 'int []'* so this is probably not the cause of error.

Comment: Also, without knowing the context and purpose of `data` in OP's implementation suggesting a `std::vector` is not advisable.

Comment: @Alok: Can you really have a VLA in a class?

Comment: A "variable length structure" compiler extension wouldn't even work, the unsized array must be the last member.

Comment: @Alok: The `-pedantic` error seems to indicate that `[]` is interpreted as `[0]`, maybe that's just because of `-pedantic`. But I wouldn't be aware of any way to set the size of that member when an instance is created, so where does the VLA get it's size from? Is there some special constructor/initializer syntax or something?

Comment: @AlokSave `std::vector` is a far better 'default' than using raw arrays and magic numbers. If there's actually a reason to have a constant sized array then `std::array` is still a better option than raw arrays, but without context vector is most likely the best option.

Comment: @bames53: I disagree without the context, One should simply refrain from suggesting a alternative.